# eclipse plugin load file

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

i have created a plugin which can load the image from the icons folder as follow:

```
Image image = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(
            FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("icons/image.gif"), null))
            .createImage();
```

It worked fine.

Similarly I have created a folder called "assets" inside eclipse plugin project, & created a file called "Temp.txt" inside it.

But I am unable to find a way to load it into my java class. Kindly help me out in getting through this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("assets/Temp.txt"), null);

URL fileUrl = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);

File file = new File(fileUrl.getPath());

... read the file in the usual way
```